# How to deal with unsupported types of fiona in python without using arcpy?

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, arcpy, fiona

I'm working on a project with GIS data from ArcGIS in a .gdb file. I wanted to use fiona/geopandas for this and use the data with some machine learning libraries. Some layers contain unsupported types, mentioned here https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/master/fiona/_geometry.pyx.

More concrete, I got UnsupportedGeometryTypeError: 11 after opening the layer and then indexing it. Some indexes have valid types, others don't.

Example:

```
with fiona.open('path.gdb', layer='layername') as layer:
  print(layer[4]) # works
  print(layer[5]) # don't work, UnsupportedGeometryTypeError: 11
```

Currently, I'm working on a mac, but can switch to a Linux distro if it solves the problem. I prefer to use free libraries and to avoid arcpy, since I need a license and e.g. ArcGIS Server.

Any ideas how can I work with those formats? Maybe additional drivers or another library? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the type of geo which is not supported?

Comment: @sagarr so far I encountered MultiCurve, but it's possible that other types are also in the dataset.

Comment: Am afraid that shapely will support proprietary geo type like multicurve, you are better off using arcpy, also ask the question on gis.stackexchange, you may get more input there.

Answer (score 2):

You could give a try to [GDAL/OGR](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/) python library. There is good chances that it supports all the geometry types that are in your fgdb.

If it's not the case, your best option would be to convert your FileGeodatabase (fgdb) which is a proprietary format (Esri) into an open format like [PostGreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/)/[PostGIS](https://postgis.net/).

You can use the command line tool [ogr2ogr](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to perform the conversion.